# Angular 2 и DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Доброго времени суток!

В приложении на **Angular 2** возникла проблема доступа к элементу `DOM` в шаблоне и вызова его метода. В шаблоне использованы компоненты **PrimeNG**, необходимо из метода `AppComponent` вызвать метод `show` элемента `OverlayPanel`. Код компонента.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('gngOp') op; 
............
onGNGKey(event){
 let ch : number;
 if (event.which == null) { // IE
   ch = event.keyCode; 
  }
 else{
 if (event.which != 0 && event.charCode != 0) { // все кроме IE
  ch = event.which;
 } 
 }
 if (ch === 13) { // окончание ввода

 if (typeof this.GNG_kod === "number" ){        // ввели лексему или часть код   а
 this.getGNGfromKod();   }
  else{
    this.getGNGfromName(this.GNG_kod);   
     }  
    } 
  }
```

**Фрагмент шаблона компонента:**

```
 <input type="text" pInputText size="6" [(ngModel)]="GNG_kod"   (keypress)="onGNGKey($event)"/>
 <input type="text" pInputText size="30" [(ngModel)]="GNG_name" /> 

 <p-overlayPanel #gngOp id="qqq" [showCloseIcon]="true" [dismissable]="false" >
 <p-dataTable [value]="GNGs" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300px" scrollWidth="500px" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="gngRow" (onRowSelect)="onGNGRowSelect($event); gngOp.hide();" >
 <p-column field="kod" ></p-column>
 <p-column field="name" ></p-column>
 <p-column field="bh1" ></p-column>
 </p-dataTable>
 </p-overlayPanel>
```

Что я не так делаю? Как корректно в моей ситуации получить доступ к элементу `OverlayPanel` и вызвать его метод `show()` ? Спасибо.

Comment: а где ты вызываешь метод show?

Comment: Пытаюсь из метода AppComponent setGNGSelect(result : GNG[]){
    ....
                  this.op.nativeElement.show();
      }  
    }

Comment: @Andrew overlayPanel  находится в компоненте AppComponent ?

Comment: @Andrew просто не совсем понятно почему нельзя обойтись *ngIf="flag" а в компаненте изменять параметр флага

Comment: Хочу на выходе получить поведение такое: вводим лексему, анализируем в обработчике события и из обработчика (фактически) открыть OverlayPanel. Да, OverlayPanel находится в шаблоне AppComponent.

Comment: _op_ у тебя должен быть _OverlayPanel_. По идее тебе надо просто вызвать: `op.show()` там где ты хочешь

Comment: по идее да https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=49733 вот тут человек аналогично его использует. У него  #opPriceGrid2 
и при клике он на кнопку он вызывает метод `show` `(click)="opPriceGrid2.show($event)" `

Comment: Можно сразу в [справке смотреть примеры](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/overlaypanel)

Comment: Воспользовался примером, все, как хотел сделал, всем спасибо за помощь :-)